# how to use exit inside here doc

Tags: bash, ssh, here-document

I have a script when I use multiple ssh connections inside HEREDOC, like so:

```
ssh -A -tt -l user 192.168.1.2 <<EOF
  ping server1 -c3
  ssh server2
  nslookup www.gogole.com
  exit
  ssh server3
  ifconfig
  exit
EOF
```

however, when I use exit inside EOF, it stops processing script instead of exiting SSH session, any idea/trick how I can exit ssh session instead of the whole script ?

```
#'~.'  - terminate session - doesn't work unfortunately
```

Comment: shouldn't you be nesting here script ? do you intend to run `nslookup www.google.com` on server2 ?

Comment: yes, I want to run nslookup www.google.com on server2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to here doc

```
ssh -A -tt -l user 192.168.1.2 <<EOF
  ping server1 -c3
  ssh server2 <<foobar1
  nslookup www.gogole.com
  more commands
  exit
foobar1
  ssh server3 <<foobar2
  ifconfig
  more more commands
  exit
foobar2
EOF
```

- you can use any word to close here doc.
- deleimiter must start a line.
- or use `<<-word`

Comment: Neither `exit` should be necessary.

Comment: actually, if I omit exit, script connects to ssh, run commands, and stops, for some reason. while when I use exit, script disconnects from ssh server and continues ..

Comment: this approach is readable and working, thanks. maybe one more thing, I had to add another 'exit' before closing EOF, to exit initial ssh connection

Comment: I think `-tt` option is responsible for those exit.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -A -tt -l user 192.168.1.2 <<EOF
  ping server1 -c3
  ssh server2 nslookup www.gogole.com
  ssh server3 ifconfig
EOF
```

The `ssh` command will exit when it has finished executing the given commands.

For multiple commands, use `sh -c`:

```
ssh -A -tt -l user 192.168.1.2 <<EOF
  ping server1 -c3
  ssh server2 sh -c 'nslookup www.gogole.com; echo done'
  ssh server3 sh -c 'ifconfig; df -k'
EOF
```

If you have more than a few basic things to do on `server2` and `server3`, create scripts on those servers and run these instead.

Comment: well yes, this will work, only that i need to run multiple commands on server2 and server3, I didn't state that in my question, my bad

Comment: @mauekunak See update.